# C++ 2d vectors | process termination error -1073741510

Tags: c++, vector, stack-overflow

I get the following statement after the program terminates: (Using Code::Blocks)

```
Process terminated with status -1073741510
```

I was getting this error before when I was trying to initialize a 2d array of size `array[800][800]`, so I found out that I needed to use 2d vectors. My code is as follows:

```
    int no_of_nodes = 800;
    vector< vector<int> > adjacency_matrix;
    for (int i = 0; i < no_of_nodes; i++){
        vector<int> aRow;
        for (int j = 0; j < no_of_nodes; j++){
            aRow.push_back(0);
        }
    adjacency_matrix.push_back(aRow);
    }
```

And I simply add to the matrix as follows:

```
//for each line in a file...
adjacency_matrix[node1][node2] = 1;
adjacency_matrix[node2][node1] = 1;
```

However I still get the stack(?) error. Any help would be much appreciated. 
I am still wanting to use large sizes of vectors > 800.

Comment: What is `node1` and `node2` in `adjacency_matrix[node1][node2]`. According to my rough calculations, you are using around 3 Megs of memory so I don't think the allocation is an issue since you are not using the stack anymore (using vectors)

Comment: I am reading from file input, `node1` and `node2` are integers per line of the file.

Comment: Is there a possibility that `node1` and `node2` indexes are negative or something ridiculous?

Comment: @StaticBeagle no, but you made me realize the issue. Since nodes in the file go up to `no_of_nodes` or 800 in my example, there was no index 800 since my for loop is `i < no_of_nodes`. It works now. Thank you haha

Comment: Aha! for some reason I kept thinking that those "nodes" were going out of bounds haha. Well I'm glad you got your issue resolved.

Comment: -1073741510 == 0xC000013A == STATUS_CONTROL_C_EXIT, "The application terminated as a result of a CTRL+C".  Feature, not a bug.